# Find all the vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ that are orthogonal to both $(1,2,3)^T$ and $(-2,0,1)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find all the vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ that are orthogonal to both $(1,2,3)^T$ and $(-2,0,1)^T$

I know that the dot product is $vw=0$ not sure how to go about setting this up.

---

Edit:

My attempt
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a &-2a\\2b&0\\3c&c\end{bmatrix} \implies 
  \begin{bmatrix}a &-2a\\2b&0\\3c&c\end{bmatrix} ^T \implies
   \begin{bmatrix}a & 2b & 3c\\-2a& 0b & c\end{bmatrix} 
   \begin{bmatrix}1a & 0b & -1/2c\\0a& 1b & 7/4c\end{bmatrix}
$$
The answer is $(1/2,-7/4,1)$. Why?

Comment: Do you know what $v\cdot w=0$ means in terms of the coordinates?

Comment: That they are perpendicular . So My first thought was that I need to set this up as a matrix and solve?

Comment: @User2648648: What's stopping you from trying?

Comment: I got the solution of the matrix as (-1/2,7/4) to the matrix but the solution is (1/2,7/4,1) . I just need help explaining the logic. I think it may have something to do with the kernel ? Just grasping at straws here

Comment: @User2648648: Please show what you have done, not just the result. If you don't show your work it is very hard to find what you have done wrong.

Comment: My Math notation is probably wrong

Comment: I believe you have set up your system of equations very strangely. See my answer below and see if you can't solve it now.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two vectors are independent, the set of mutually orthogonal vectors forms a line.  Moreover, this line consists of all vectors which are scalar multiples of $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are your two vectors.  Start calculating....

Comment: It sounds like you are using points and vectors interchangeably here. A line is a set of points, not a set of vectors.

Comment: Then the OP is free to erase the pointy brackets in $\langle x, y, z \rangle$ and replace them with parens to create $(x, y, z)$ and then move on with life.

Comment: I don't see any pointy brackets (except in your comment). What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The exchange of vectors (pointy) to points (paren) doesn't influence the final result that much, and comes down to semantics.  In fact, it is common to call the function $t \mapsto t\mathbf{v}$ a "line" even though it consists of vector outputs.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Using better notation, you are looking for all vectors $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(x,y,z)\cdot(1,2,3)&=0\\
(x,y,z)\cdot(-2,0,1)&=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Cross product is perpendicular to both

$\{1,2,3\}\times \{-2,0,1\}=\{2,-7,4\}$

so any vector $t\,\{2,-7,4\},\;\forall t\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

satisfies the request